# Unity error while building , JDK and SDK not found

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, sdk

[image: un]

Please Help,I have installed JDK and SDK for Unity, both manually and with unity hub, but all the time the message occurs while building, that JDK and SDK are invalid or not found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Android Studio (SDK) and also Oracle JDK.

If you still can't solve the problem, make sure you download
the following modules - 
**Android build support**, **Android SDK & NDK tools** and **Open JDK**